# Extracting CGI query parameter values in bash

Tags: regex, bash, cgi, query-string, extract

All right, folks, you may have seen this infamous quirk to get hold of those values:

```
query=`echo $QUERY_STRING | sed "s/=/='/g; s/&/';/g; s/$/'/"`
eval $query
```

If the query string is host=example.com&port=80 it works just fine and you get the values in bash variables host and port. 
However, you may know that a cleverly crafted query string will cause an arbitrary command to be executed on the server side. 
I'm looking for a secure replacement or an alternative not using eval. After some research I dug up these alternatives:

```
read host port <<< $(echo "$QUERY_STRING" | tr '=&' '  ' | cut -d ' ' -f 2,4)
echo $host
echo $port
```

and

```
if [[ $QUERY_STRING =~ ^host=([^&]*)\&port=(.*)$ ]]
then
    echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    echo ${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
else
    echo no match, sorry
fi
```

Unfortunately these two alternatives only work if the pars come in the order host,port. But they could come in the opposite order.
There could also be more than 2 pars, and any order is possible and allowed. So how do you propose to get the values into the
appropriate bash vars? Can the above methods be amended? Remember that with n pars there are n! possible orders. With 2 pars
there are only 2, but with 3 pars there are already 3! = 6.

I returned to the first method. Can it be made safe to run eval? Can you transform $QUERY_STRING with sed in a way that 
makes it safe to do eval $query ?

EDIT: Note that this question differs from the other one referred to and is not a duplicate. The emphasis here is on using eval in a safe way. That is not answered in the other thread.

Comment: @LéaGris See the edit above.

Comment: There is no such thing as a safe use of `eval`, especially when processing foreign tainted data as query strings. Also the other question and its answers already address the use and dangers of `eval` to parse a CGI query string.

Comment: @LéaGris No safe use of eval? Prove it! The other thread doesn't address the issue, neither proves nor disproves.

Answer (score 3):

This method is safe. It does not eval or execute the QUERY_STRING. It uses string manipulation to break up the string into pieces:

```
QUERY_STRING='host=example.com&port=80'

declare -a pairs
IFS='&' read -ra pairs <<<"$QUERY_STRING"

declare -A values
for pair in "${pairs[@]}"; do
    IFS='=' read -r key value <<<"$pair"
    values["$key"]="$value"
done

echo do something with "${values[host]}" and "${values[port]}"
```

URL "percent decoding" left as an exercise.

Comment: What's the point in using associative arrays like this when they are built into the language? You can do a=x; eval $a=hello; echo $x and hello is printed.

Comment: ``a='`some malicious program` x'; eval $a=hello`` -- avoid `eval` whenever possible, and here is it clearly possible.

Comment: Note that I assigned a myself.

Comment: Yes but you don't assign QUERY_STRING yourself

Comment: True, and that's the problem to be solved.

Comment: And do you think I have not solved it?

Comment: I appreciate your contribution but what I had in mind was a modification of the eval method first given in my text to make it safe. Something short and neat, yet provably safe.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "I'm looking for a secure replacement or an alternative not using eval."

Comment: To qualify as a solution it must be short and elegant, like the 3 methods given in my text. One or two lines. And secure. And cover all possible input.

Answer (score 1):

You must avoid executing strings at all time when they come from untrusted sources. Therefore I would strongly suggest never to use `eval` in Bash do something with a string.

To be really save, I think I would echo the string into a file, use grep to retrieve parts of the string and remove the file afterwards. Always use a directory out of the web root.

```sh
#! /bin/bash

MYFILE=$(mktemp)
QUERY_STRING='host=example.com&port=80&host=lepmaxe.moc&port=80'

echo "${QUERY_STRING}" > ${MYFILE}
TMP_ARR=($(grep -Eo '(host|port)[^&]*' ${MYFILE}))

[ ${#TMP_ARR} -gt 0 ]          || exit 1
[ $((${#TMP_ARR} % 2)) -eq 0 ] || exit 1

declare -A ARRAY;
for ((i = 0; i < ${#TMP_ARR[@]}; i+=2)); do
    tmp=$(echo ${TMP_ARR[@]:$((i)):2})
    port=$(echo $tmp | sed -r 's/.*port=([^ ]*).*/\1/')
    host=$(echo $tmp | sed -r 's/.*host=([^ ]*).*/\1/')
    ARRAY[$host]=$port
done

for i in ${!ARRAY[@]}; do
        echo "$i = ${ARRAY[$i]}"
done

rm ${MYFILE}
exit 0
```

This produces:

```
lepmaxe.moc = 80
example.com = 80
```